# How to call a fragment inside a Adapter class?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, adapter

I want to call fragment (DescDenuncia) and replace it inside (frameLayout), I've already tried the line that is highlighted but something still missing in the code I don't know why is the "getSupportFragmentManager()" line in red, what should i do?

```
//Vinculando o reclycler view ao firestore
public class Adapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Modelo, Adapter.myviewholder> {


    public Adapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Modelo> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    //Sobrescrevendo o método
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull final Modelo model) {
        //Associando os itens do atalho ocorrências
        holder.IDText.setText(model.getID());
        holder.tipoText.setText(model.getTipo());
        Glide.with(holder.img1.getContext()).load(model.getImg()).into(holder.img1);

        ///////////////////////////////////////THE PROBLEM IS HERE///////////////////////////////////////////
        holder.RLAYOUT.setOnClickListener(new View. OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, new DescDenuncia(
                )).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            }
        });
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.modelo_atalho_ocorrencias, parent, false);
        return new myviewholder(view);

    }

    //Coneção do reclycler view com essa classe
    public class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        //Variáveis do modelo atalho
        TextView tipoText, IDText;
        RelativeLayout RLAYOUT;
        ImageView img1;

        //Associando os objetos ao modelo atalho
        public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            tipoText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTipo);
            img1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            IDText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtModeloID);
            RLAYOUT = itemView.findViewById(R.id.RLlayout);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you can not reach getSupportFragmentManager() from adapter unless you send your fragment to the adapter. Where you send your data to adapter just put a comma and send your fragment using 'this' keyword.

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(new Adapter(model, this));
```

Create global fragment variable in your adapter:

```
private Fragment currentFragment = null;
```

Then get the fragment you sent from, to your adapter's fragment variable so you can use anywhere in your adapter:

```
public Adapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Modelo> options, Fragment fragment) {
        currentFragment = fragment;
        super(options);
    }
```

Now you can reach getSupportFragmentManager() like below:

```
fragment.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, new DescDenuncia(
                )).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```